# Is Java driver 4.x compatible with Cassandra 3.x clusters?

Tags: java, performance, cassandra

We are using Java 4+ driver with Cassandra 3x cluster and seeing performance issues.

Expecting good performance intermittently. Seeing a lot of driver timeout exceptions and read timeout exceptions. Any pointers would help.

Comment: Please start by answering me this: What is a Java 4+ driver?

Comment: Please read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This questions doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, version 4.x of the Java drivers are compatible with Cassandra 3.0 and 3.11 clusters.

For details, see the [Java driver compatibility matrix](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/docs/java-drivers.html).

Without knowing details of the issue you are facing, my best guess is that your cluster is overloaded leading to the timeout exceptions. Cheers!

Comment: If only OP had included a pom so we could see what they're talking about. Not that your guess here is wrong.